# phpmyadmin: #2003 Cannot log in to the MySQL server after successful login

Tags: phpmyadmin

Just moved to a new mysql server (version 5.1.69 on CentOS 6.4) and application (running on Cent OS 5.8, PHP 5.3.3 w/custom mysql and mysqli libraries built against mysql 5.1.69) runs fine. PhpMyAdmin 4.0.5 logs in fine, but as soon as I click any link, I get

```
#2003 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Create a user for your web application with the same credentials as you have in your web application's configuration.

Comment: Maybe it's your phpMyAdmin's control user that cannot log in? Is it properly configured?

Comment: Paulpro: I am using the same login as my application. 

Marc Delisle: I was getting complaints about the control user until I set it up. I suppose it is possible I did something wrong for the control user. Will double check.

Comment: After opening up some broader user access, for both the application and pma users, I still get the same #2003 after login problem. Have confirmed that the application is still up, and I can log into and use both users from the cli.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you deactivate the pmadb in config.inc.php? Also, when you have the #2003 message, does it say for which user?

Comment: Same error, and it doesn't show which user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem for me. I can connect via mysql CLI, but still get the same error message

In the end, I found the solution: this is an SELinux issue. You can solve this by two ways:

1. disable selinux . command:
   `"setenforce 0"`
2. allow httpd connect db via scripts. command:
   `"setsebool -P  httpd_can_network_connect_db on"`

Comment: It's a shame that I didn't return to this post when I solved it. SELinux does seem like it could be the culprit. It's been years since this was an issue, and I honestly don't recall how I solved it.